# Error: processing response error ........... In my solidity smartcontract

Tags: blockchain, solidity, smartcontracts, ganache

```
const ethers = require("ethers");
const fs = require("fs-extra");
async function main() {
    const provider = new ethers.providers.JsonRpcProvider("http://172.24.176.1:7545"); //connection to the blockchain
    const wallet = new ethers.Wallet("0x44de1f6eb319a19bba28e27d535f3774a476c052ebcbd8e7a18c17832d956a6b", provider); //a wallet in the blockchain we've connected to
    //which takes in private key and provider ie blockchain //it helps us sign our txns in the blockchain to encrypt them
    const abi = fs.readFileSync("./SimpleStorage_sol_SimpleStorage.abi", "utf-8"); //reads the abi file synchronously in order
    const binary = fs.readFileSync("./SimpleStorage_sol_SimpleStorage.bin", "utf-8"); //reads the bin file synchronously in order
    //to deploy contract
    const contractFactory = new ethers.ContractFactory(abi, binary, wallet); //describes which particular contract needs to be fetched
    console.log("Deploying please wait");
    const deployOptions = { gasLimit: 2000000 };
    const contract = await contractFactory.deploy(deployOptions);
    //const contract = await contractFactory.deploy({gasLimit: 10000}); //deploys the fetched contract and await keyword is used to resolve the deploying of a contract to a contract obj but without await it will just return a promise
    console.log(contract);
}

main()
    .then(() => {
        process.exit(0);
    })
    .catch((error) => {
        console.log(error);
        process.exit(1);
    });
```

I am trying to deploy a solidity smartcontract using ganache and it gives me this error....

> Error: processing response error (body="{"id":51,"jsonrpc":"2.0","error":{"message":"VM Exception while processing transaction: invalid opcode","stack":"RuntimeError: VM Exception while processing transaction: invalid opcode\n    at EIP1559FeeMarketTransaction.fillFromResult (C:\\Program Files\\WindowsApps\\GanacheUI_2.7.1.0_x64__rb4352f0jd4m2\\app\\resources\\static\\node\\node_modules\\ganache\\dist\\node\\1.js:2:12745)\n    at Miner. (C:\\Program Files\\WindowsApps\\GanacheUI_2.7.1.0_x64__rb4352f0jd4m2\\app\\resources\\static\\node\\node_modules\\ganache\\dist\\node\\1.js:2:36703)\n    at async Miner. (C:\\Program Files\\WindowsApps\\GanacheUI_2.7.1.0_x64__rb4352f0jd4m2\\app\\resources\\static\\node\\node_modules\\ganache\\dist\\node\\1.js:2:35116)\n    at async Miner.mine (C:\\Program Files\\WindowsApps\\GanacheUI_2.7.1.0_x64__rb4352f0jd4m2\\app\\resources\\static\\node\\node_modules\\ganache\\dist\\node\\1.js:2:39680)\n    at async Blockchain.mine (C:\\Program Files\\WindowsApps\\GanacheUI_2.7.1.0_x64__rb4352f0jd4m2\\app\\resources\\static\\node\\node_modules\\ganache\\dist\\node\\1.js:2:60063)\n    at async Promise.all (index 0)\n    at async TransactionPool.emit (C:\\Program Files\\WindowsApps\\GanacheUI_2.7.1.0_x64__rb4352f0jd4m2\\app\\resources\\static\\node\\node_modules\\ganache\\node_modules\\emittery\\index.js:303:3)","code":-32000,"name":"RuntimeError","data":{"hash":"0x173bf65022c412660b27bcebec6faf923c5e53a6266a177a24bcf64642e41ce6","programCounter":24,"result":"0x173bf65022c412660b27bcebec6faf923c5e53a6266a177a24bcf64642e41ce6","reason":null,"message":"invalid opcode"}}}", error={"code":-32000,"data":{"hash":"0x173bf65022c412660b27bcebec6faf923c5e53a6266a177a24bcf64642e41ce6","programCounter":24,"result":"0x173bf65022c412660b27bcebec6faf923c5e53a6266a177a24bcf64642e41ce6","reason":null,"message":"invalid opcode"}}, requestBody="{"method":"eth_sendRawTransaction","params":["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"],"id":51,"jsonrpc":"2.0"}", requestMethod="POST", url="http://172.24.176.1:7545", code=SERVER_ERROR, version=web/5.7.1)
> at Logger.makeError (/home/raghav_dev/Blockchain/ethersSimpleStorage/node_modules/@ethersproject/logger/lib/index.js:238:21)
> at Logger.throwError (/home/raghav_dev/Blockchain/ethersSimpleStorage/node_modules/@ethersproject/logger/lib/index.js:247:20)
> at /home/raghav_dev/Blockchain/ethersSimpleStorage/node_modules/@ethersproject/web/lib/index.js:313:32
> at step (/home/raghav_dev/Blockchain/ethersSimpleStorage/node_modules/@ethersproject/web/lib/index.js:33:23)
> at Object.next (/home/raghav_dev/Blockchain/ethersSimpleStorage/node_modules/@ethersproject/web/lib/index.js:14:53)
> at fulfilled (/home/raghav_dev/Blockchain/ethersSimpleStorage/node_modules/@ethersproject/web/lib/index.js:5:58)
> at process.processTicksAndRejections (node:internal/process/task_queues:95:5) {
> reason: 'processing response error',
> code: 'SERVER_ERROR',
> body: '{"id":51,"jsonrpc":"2.0","error":{"message":"VM Exception while processing transaction: invalid opcode","stack":"RuntimeError: VM Exception while processing transaction: invalid opcode\n    at EIP1559FeeMarketTransaction.fillFromResult (C:\\Program Files\\WindowsApps\\GanacheUI_2.7.1.0_x64__rb4352f0jd4m2\\app\\resources\\static\\node\\node_modules\\ganache\\dist\\node\\1.js:2:12745)\n    at Miner. (C:\\Program Files\\WindowsApps\\GanacheUI_2.7.1.0_x64__rb4352f0jd4m2\\app\\resources\\static\\node\\node_modules\\ganache\\dist\\node\\1.js:2:36703)\n    at async Miner. (C:\\Program Files\\WindowsApps\\GanacheUI_2.7.1.0_x64__rb4352f0jd4m2\\app\\resources\\static\\node\\node_modules\\ganache\\dist\\node\\1.js:2:35116)\n    at async Miner.mine (C:\\Program Files\\WindowsApps\\GanacheUI_2.7.1.0_x64__rb4352f0jd4m2\\app\\resources\\static\\node\\node_modules\\ganache\\dist\\node\\1.js:2:39680)\n    at async Blockchain.mine (C:\\Program Files\\WindowsApps\\GanacheUI_2.7.1.0_x64__rb4352f0jd4m2\\app\\resources\\static\\node\\node_modules\\ganache\\dist\\node\\1.js:2:60063)\n    at async Promise.all (index 0)\n    at async TransactionPool.emit (C:\\Program Files\\WindowsApps\\GanacheUI_2.7.1.0_x64__rb4352f0jd4m2\\app\\resources\\static\\node\\node_modules\\ganache\\node_modules\\emittery\\index.js:303:3)","code":-32000,"name":"RuntimeError","data":{"hash":"0x173bf65022c412660b27bcebec6faf923c5e53a6266a177a24bcf64642e41ce6","programCounter":24,"result":"0x173bf65022c412660b27bcebec6faf923c5e53a6266a177a24bcf64642e41ce6","reason":null,"message":"invalid opcode"}}}',
> error: Error: VM Exception while processing transaction: invalid opcode
> at getResult (/home/raghav_dev/Blockchain/ethersSimpleStorage/node_modules/@ethersproject/providers/lib/json-rpc-provider.js:191:21)
> at processJsonFunc (/home/raghav_dev/Blockchain/ethersSimpleStorage/node_modules/@ethersproject/web/lib/index.js:356:22)
> at /home/raghav_dev/Blockchain/ethersSimpleStorage/node_modules/@ethersproject/web/lib/index.js:288:46
> at step (/home/raghav_dev/Blockchain/ethersSimpleStorage/node_modules/@ethersproject/web/lib/index.js:33:23)
> at Object.next (/home/raghav_dev/Blockchain/ethersSimpleStorage/node_modules/@ethersproject/web/lib/index.js:14:53)
> at fulfilled (/home/raghav_dev/Blockchain/ethersSimpleStorage/node_modules/@ethersproject/web/lib/index.js:5:58)
> at process.processTicksAndRejections (node:internal/process/task_queues:95:5) {
> code: -32000,
> data: {
> hash: '0x173bf65022c412660b27bcebec6faf923c5e53a6266a177a24bcf64642e41ce6',
> programCounter: 24,
> result: '0x173bf65022c412660b27bcebec6faf923c5e53a6266a177a24bcf64642e41ce6',
> reason: null,
> message: 'invalid opcode'
> }
> },
> requestBody: '{"method":"eth_sendRawTransaction","params":["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"],"id":51,"jsonrpc":"2.0"}',
> requestMethod: 'POST',
> url: 'http://172.24.176.1:7545',
> transaction: {
> type: 2,
> chainId: 1337,
> nonce: 4,
> maxPriorityFeePerGas: BigNumber { _hex: '0x59682f00', _isBigNumber: true },
> maxFeePerGas: BigNumber { _hex: '0xae256400', _isBigNumber: true },
> gasPrice: null,
> gasLimit: BigNumber { _hex: '0x1e8480', _isBigNumber: true },
> to: null,
> value: BigNumber { _hex: '0x00', _isBigNumber: true },
> data: '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',
> accessList: [],
> hash: '0x173bf65022c412660b27bcebec6faf923c5e53a6266a177a24bcf64642e41ce6',
> v: 0,
> r: '0x9f7d1f8f4811588ca6b6ae1c33268fa9d97bf13b0b96d6a81fd01b5a1ee32e3b',
> s: '0x15413104b3794c78ee60c36a9a596ad56f61539b8455427ed5e8398f0f3ddf26',
> from: '0xcdc376Ee46cE1699Ae2fB81B9c5442A444547F84',
> confirmations: 0
> },
> transactionHash: '0x173bf65022c412660b27bcebec6faf923c5e53a6266a177a24bcf64642e41ce6'

these are my dependencies:
{
"dependencies": {
"ethers": "^5.7.2",
"fs-extra": "^11.1.1",
"ganache": "^7.9.0",
"solc": "0.8.7-fixed"
},
"scripts": {
"compile": "yarn solcjs --bin --abi --include-path node_modules/ --base-path . -o . SimpleStorage.sol"
}
}